# Digits in LFT Etica font are displayed in different heights

Tags: css, fonts, font-feature-settings

I'm working on an application where we are to use the font LFT Etica. However, when displaying numbers, some of the digits are noticeably taller than the other ones. How can I get the height of the digits to equal height? Preferably without changing the font. It looks like 0, 2, 3, 6, 8, and 9 are displayed tall, and 1, 4, 5, and 7 are short.

[Screenshot of current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQUxM.png)

I have tried adjusting the CSS properties `font-variant-numeric` and `font-variant` without any luck. This is how my CSS currently looks:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5715;
    font-family: LFT Etica, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
    font-feature-settings: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 100000000px;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?